# Curve_fit returns 1.0 when data number is increased

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I've been trying to perform a histogram fitting to some data. When the number of bins of the histogram is between 12 and about 300, the code works great, but when I increase the number of bins, it returns a flat line.

I checked to see if it's the histogram's fault, but the data comes out fine in spite of the bins number...

```
def f_func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c

popt, pcov = opt.curve_fit(f_func, hist_x, hist_y)

print("f = ", round(popt[0], 2), "* exp(-", round(popt[2], 2), "* x) +", round(popt[2], 2))
```

[300 bins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87Gkr.png)
[500 bins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hu74r.png)

Comment: When curve_fit cannot improve on the inital parameter estimates, it simply returns them. Since you are not providing any initial parameter estimates of your own, it is using the default initial parameter estimates of all 1.0. One experiment to try is to use the fitted values for 300 as the initial parameter estimates for, say, 400 and see if that fixes the problem. That would prove that you would need to provide your own initial parameter estimates for larger numbers.